# dewarping the fish eye images using android application

Tags: java, android, opencv, fisheye

I am working on android app. Currently my app is used as a viewer for camera.

The camera side handle the fish eye dewarp mode. my app is just  used to view the dewarp mode stream.

Now we are looking for a way to implement fish eye dewarping mode and handle on application side in android.

I am totally new into this . I wish to know

1. is there any library (open or paid) where in i can give the fish eye images and the library gives me the dewarped view mode.
2. Does Android provide any api to dewarp (flatten image) for fish eye camera ?

I wish to implement an application with android, having a feature to able to dewarp and view the fish eye views from the camera.

any help in this would be great .

Answer (score 1):

1. OpenCV has fisheyeUndistort method, as well as methods for estimating distortion parameters, consider the [manual](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/d58/group__calib3d__fisheye.html#gsc.tab=0), [this](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html) and [this](http://ninghang.blogspot.ru/2012/08/fish-eye-camera-calibration.html).
2. I don't think so.

Comment: thank you for sharing details about open cv. I am confused about how the flow or architecture looks like...if i use ffmpeg library, do i need to see it as : Camera -- fish eye image -- scalar -- ffmpeg library --- opencv (for dewarp) -- application show . I dont know the flow ..can you let me know if my understanding is wrong..